# How can i rename an android phone's .jpg file in a specific pattern using python 3?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, renaming

I'm still very new to programming with Python 3 and know almost nothing about it. I was told that Python is both powerful and easy to learn.

Right now I'm trying to rename some .jpg files from my android phone into a certain pattern. The usual pattern of a normal .jpg file(taken with the camera) from my android phone looks like this: `YYYYMMDD_hhmmss.jpg` and im trying to change it into this pattern: `YYYY-MM-DD hh-mm-ss.jpg`

This is the code i wrote so far:

```
import re
import os

for filename in os.listdir(".") #here is the path to the .jpg files
    m = re.match(r"(\d{8})_(\d{6})\.jpg", filename)
    if m:
        newname = (r"(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\.jpg)
        if not os.path.exists(newname):
            os.rename(filename, newname)
```

When i run the program the shell alone doesn't really show me an error message.
It only says this:

> =====RESTART: (a path that leads to the .py file that my code is written in)======

After that i ran the debugger through the Python Shell and it said:

> KeyError:(, '(\d{8})_(\d{6})\.jpg'0)   (in the
>   debugger)
>
> _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".47860048.41027664.41027120" (in the shell after debugging)

I dont know what it means or what i can do to make this work.

Thanks in advance for every answer i might get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `re.sub` and `backreference`

```
import re
import os

FOLDER_PATH = "."   #set your path here
for filename in os.listdir(FOLDER_PATH):    
    newname = re.sub("(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})_(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})\.jpg"
                , r"\1-\2-\3 \4-\5-\6.jpg"
                , filename)
    if (newname != filename and (not os.path.exists(os.path.join(FOLDER_PATH, newname)))):
        os.rename(os.path.join(FOLDER_PATH, filename), os.path.join(FOLDER_PATH, newname))
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick help. I i just tried to use your code and it seems to work, but for some reason it cant find the files. But it must know what file i want it to rename because the program says only what pattern it searches

Comment: --> and what path the files are in. It shows in the error message that it knows what file it's trying to rename because its showing the exact name of the file that im trying to rename.

Comment: Thanks @yosefrow for this comment and your suggestion of editing. I rejrect your edit because IMO if OP want to improve his regex skill, he should search himself using above keyword

Comment: @TheHero2805 The code seems ok. Could you show your new error message?

Comment: @PhamX.Bach Sure thing. this is what shows up in the python shell after i run the code. FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden: '20160606_170101.jpg' -> '2016-06-06 17-01-01.jpg' the sentence after [WinnError 2] means the system cant find the mentioned file.

Comment: @TheHero2805 because you use a custom path to your jpg folder, you should set the `FOLDER_PATH` so `os` could find the files. See my edited answer.

Comment: @PhamX.Bach Thank you for your help! it works perfectly! ^~^

Comment: @PhamX.Bach You're welcome. But what is the reasoning behind preferring to make people Google something and refusing to give them a link to an actual resource? Is it because of the policy regarding being too broad? I thought it would contribute to the completeness of the answer.

You told him to use a backreference, but you didn't indicate on which line the backreference was located. Also backreferences look different in each language. So there's no guarantee he will find a resource that shows him what a python backreference looks like.

Comment: @yosefrow Thank you. The reson is: it's **all about me**. Keep calm. IMO, one should not teach a guy how to fish. What he need is `fishing-spirit`. Again, it's all about me.

Comment: @PhamX.Bach That's fair enough. I thought i was missing some rule about the site. Its your answer, so at the end of the day you decide what you feel like sharing and what you rather not share :)